# Filter data on the basis of dropdown selection in Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller

I want to filter data on the basis of city dropdown alphabetical filter working fine but when i used dropdown and fiter dropdown selection then it will return wrong data 
please check my code here

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/Nayeem_Mansoori/yhy7hdrh/][1]
```

please help me.

Comment: where is your dropdown in your fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nayeem_Mansoori/yhy7hdrh/2/

Answer (score 1):

When I want to filter one field only o do like it:

```
<li ng-repeat="cust in Customer | filter: { Name: myfilters } | orderBy: Name">{{cust.Name}}</li>
```

filter by properties use **filter: { Name: myfilters }**

http://jsfiddle.net/yhy7hdrh/4/

--- Some time later ---

I think I understand, chosing a city you want to filter by letter the Name of customer... http://jsfiddle.net/yhy7hdrh/8/

Comment: please check  
jsfiddle.net/Nayeem_Mansoori/yhy7hdrh/2

Comment: its not working data not filter on the basis of city

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand

Comment: oh sorry, just trying to help

Comment: yes got it but when dropdown worked then alphanetical click not work so my question is both filter can't work paralally

Comment: Are you sure its not working? I set more values in Customer json... the the problem is when I chose letter O and show "Antony" and "Bruno", but has a alphabetical order. http://jsfiddle.net/yhy7hdrh/9/

Comment: I am sorry if cant understand what you need. :s

Answer (score 0):

I think u made a smallllll mistake :)

use like this

```
<li ng-repeat="cust in Customer | filter: myfilters | orderBy: 'Name'">{{cust.Name}}</li>
```

please put the `Name` as a string in orderBy as `'Name'`

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/majrzurv/)

in order to filter by those two drop downs you need two separate filters, in angular its so simple as below line,

```
<li ng-repeat="cust in Customer | filter:selectedValue | filter:CityselectedValue | orderBy: 'Name'">
```

first it filter in `selectedValue` which is the first dropdown, and the second filter filters the results according to second dropdown.

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mf2ae47b/)

more specifically use can use like this,

first dropdown

```
    <select ng-model="selectedValue.Name" n..
```

second dropdown

```
    <select ng-model="selectedValue.City" ng-opti..
```

in `ng-repeat`

```
<li ng-repeat="cust in Customer | filter:selectedValue | orderBy: 'Name'">
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gmxundrc/)

Comment: ok, please select city dropdown afterthat click "A" or click "All" its not work

Comment: when dropdown worked then alphanetical click not work so my question is both filter can't work paralally